# Making loops kind of async / wait in JavaScript / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of user objects which I fetch from a (Firestore) database looking similar to this:

```
let users = [
  { name: 'max', role: 1, company_id: 14 },
  { name: 'steve', role: 3, company_id: 29 },
  { name: 'anna', role: 5, company_id: 124 }
];
```

There are two tables `user_roles` and `companies` where I need to fetch data like the respective role name or company name from. I'm achieving it by looping through the `users` array and using observables to get data from Firestore. The fetched data is added to the respective user so my `users` array now contains info about the name of the user's company.

```
for (let user of users) {

  // Define all observables
  const role_data = firebase.getRoleData(user.role);
  const company_data = firebase.getCompanyData(user.company_id);

  // Join observables to one stream
  const join_stream = combineLatest([role_data, company_data]);

  // Subscribe to that joined stream and fetch info
  join_stream.subscribe(([role_data, company_data]) => {
    user.role_name = role_data['role_name'];
    user.company_name = company_data['company_name'];
  });

}
```

Is there any way to detect when the `for` loop is done so I can show/hide a loading spinner? I thought of implementing a counter checking the length of the `users` array but that doesn't seem to be an elegant way.

I doesn't have to be solved by using rxjs or similar, every working solution or hint is welcome. Maybe some async stuff? I haven't found anything suitable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let me know if it works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: If you make the function where this is called in `async`, you can `await` all of the async operations and show a loading spinner/notice

Comment: Which part of the operation in the `for` loop is asynchronous? If order is not important, you can simply push promises into an array and then do `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understood correctly. Is this what you're looking for?

```js
let users = [
  { name: 'max', role: 1, company_id: 14 },
  { name: 'steve', role: 3, company_id: 29 },
  { name: 'anna', role: 5, company_id: 124 }
];

for (let [i, user] of users.entries()) {

  // Define all observables
  // ...
  
  // Join observables to one stream
  // ...

  // Subscribe to that joined stream and fetch info
  // ...
  
  if (i+1 === users.length) {
    console.log('Finished!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the counter thing I talked about. But I was wondering if there's some async / await technique or similar to prevent counting stuff. Thanks anyways, +1 for a working solution!

Comment: As Terry said above, you could create a solution using `Promise.all();`, but I can't think of any other solution that would be more elegant than checking the index against the array length. Glad I could lend my thoughts regardless!